# Migrate Classic Loadbalancer to Application Loadbalancer in EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, load-balancing, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to migrate my CLB to ALB. I know there is a direct option on the AWS loadbalancer UI console to do a migration. But I don't want to use that. I have a service file which deploys classic loadbalancer on EKS using kubectl.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations: {service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: '3600',
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: classic}
  name: helloworld
spec:
  ports:
  - {name: https, port: 8443, protocol: TCP, targetPort: 8080}
  - {name: http, port: 8080, protocol: TCP, targetPort: 8080}
  selector: {app: helloworld}
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I want to convert it into ALB. I tried the following approach but not worked.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloworld
spec:
  ports:
  - {name: https, port: 8443, protocol: TCP, targetPort: 8080}
  - {name: http, port: 8080, protocol: TCP, targetPort: 8080}
  selector: {app: helloworld}
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: helloworld
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=dev,Team=app**
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "*.amazonaws.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /echo
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: helloworld
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

It has not created any loadbalancer. When I did `kubectl get ingress`, It showed me the ingress but it has no address. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

your Ingress file seems to be correct,

for having ALB installed automatically from an Ingress you should install the [AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/) which manages AWS Elastic Load Balancers for a Kubernetes cluster.

You can follow [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html) and then verify that it is installed correctly:

```
kubectl get deployment -n kube-system aws-load-balancer-controller
```

apply:

```
kubectl apply -f service-ingress.yaml
```

and verify that your ALB, TG, etc are created:

```
kubectl logs deploy/aws-load-balancer-controller -n kube-system --follow
```